# Does React use the document API under the hood?

Tags: reactjs, dom

I've been learning React and I've learned that JSX elements are turned into React.CreateElement calls, I've also seen the output of this is an object that gets created which includes the tag name, props etc.

I wondered though as the document has an API to create elements and get elements etc, is this what React eventually ends up using behind the scenes to insert a new element in the DOM or when updating content in the DOM or is it using something completely different?